# Is there any way of showing icon for .py files?

Tags: python, windows

Firstly, I opened the Python file with `notepad`, and another day I right clicked the Python file and opened it with Python IDLE and from that day on, Python files are not showing the Python icon. Which is not looking good.

These are all Python files:

[image: screenshot of list of files]

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry it is just the preferred setting for opening .py files in Windows.

You can change this by left clicking a .py file -> from the drop down menu select 'Open with' -> 'Choose another app' -> Select the program you want. This could be Notepad, IDLE, or something else you prefer. Tick the 'Always open...' if you want Windows to remember your choice.